# Parar uma requisição ajax e criar uma nova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Em um input de pesquisa, uma requisição ajax é feita a cada letra pressionada através de um KeyPress no campo, porém a cada tecla pressionada uma nova requisição é feita, ou seja se o usuário digita rápido, e ele digitar um valor de 10 letras, 10 requisições diferentes serão feitas, e as mesmas 10 serão processadas e mandadas de volta pelo meu PHP, e isso pode me causar alguma confusão no retorno desses dados para o usuário caso uma solicitação anterior seja processada com atraso, logo eu quero que a cada tecla pressionada, as requisições anteriores sejam abortadas e então envia a nova requisição.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".meuInput", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val != ''){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "meuarquivo.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {src: val},
        success: function(data)
        {
            //processa retorno
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leo, o `$.ajax` retorna um objeto do tipo `jqXHR`, e por questões de compatibilidade ele mantem alguns métodos e propriedades em comum com o `XMLHttpRequest`, dentre eles o `.abort()`.

```
var jqRequest = null;
$(document).on("keypress", ".meuInput", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val != ''){
        if (jqRequest)
            jqRequest.abort();
        jqRequest = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "meuarquivo.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data: {src: val},
            success: function(data)
            {
                //processa retorno
            }
        });
    }
});
```

mas note que neste caso, não há controle de qual `input` chamou esta função, então talvez seja interessante manter um controle mais refinado.

```
var inputs = [];
var jqRequests = {};

$(document).on("keypress", ".meuInput", function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val != ''){      
        if (inputs.indexOf(e.currentTarget) == -1)
            inputs.push(e.currentTarget);
        var indice = inputs.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
        if (jqRequests[indice])
            jqRequests[indice].abort();         
        jqRequests[indice] = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "meuarquivo.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data: {src: val},
            success: function(data)
            {
                //processa retorno
            }
        });
    }
});
```

e por fim, a sua aplicação teria um desempenho melhor caso adiciona-se um pequeno delay antes de realizar a requisição AJAX.

```
var myDelay = null;
$(document).on("keypress", ".meuInput", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val != ''){
        if (myDelay)
            window.clearInterval(myDelay);
        myDelay = window.setTimeout(function () {
            myDelay = null;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "meuarquivo.php",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {src: val},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //processa retorno
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: A terceira opção, com delay na requisição não tem necessidade abortar as requisições?

Comment: @LeoLetto o delay serve para evitar que sejam feitas requisições AJAX enquanto o usuário ainda está digitando, no exemplo acima a requisição AJAX será feita 2 segundos apos o usuário terminar de digitar.

Comment: Se eu reduzir esse delay pra 500, perderia algum desempenho? Pois 2 segundos achei um pouco grande

Comment: @LeoLetto não existe um valor ideal, apenas se lembre que pequenas interrupções são normais enquanto você digita, então 0.5s pode ser um tempo pequeno para alguns usuários, então o ideal é buscar um bom ponto de equilíbrio

Comment: Acho que vou optar pela segunda opção e fazer um post a cada letra digitada, e interrompe-lo, da uma impressão de um retorno mais rápido e resolve o problema das requisições em excesso, Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @LeoLetto acho que não resolve, entenda, fazer um `.abort()` não significa que a requisição no lado do servidor vai ser interrompida, caso a mesma já tenha sido entregue, o PHP vai fazer todo o trabalho dele, porém o Browser vai ignorar o retorno.

Comment: uma opção para aliviar o lado do servidor, é definir um tamanho minimo a pesquisar, tipo 3 letras, com um intervalo de 0.5s e no minimo 3 caracteres, acredito que terá uma boa relação desempenho com experiencia do usuario.

Comment: O problema de limitar os caracteres é que os valores a serem pesquisados podem variar entende? Se o usuário quiser por exemplo pesquisar todos os resultados com a letra A e eu limitar a pesquisa  2 ou mais caracteres ele não vai ter acesso aos resultados por letra, essa solução é mais para pessoas com internet mais lenta

Comment: Fiz o teste em conexões de 5mb acima, as requisições são mandadas e processadas na ordem em que foram digitadas, porém abaixo disso algumas novas são enviadas primeiro do que as anteriores, causando bug na exibição

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```js
$(document).on("keypress", ".meuInput", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val != '') {
    setTimeout(minhafuncao, 500);
    //não coloque () ou a função vai ser executada ignorando os 500ms.
  }
});


var minhaFuncao = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "meuarquivo.php",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {
      src: val
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //processa retorno
    }
  });
}
```